# beautifulsoup for getting all links from base URL in a website

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I want to get all links/html pages from website base URL. I read documents and got to know it can be achieved using python Beautifulsoup combination. Can you please let me know how to install BeautifulSoup and any other pre-requisite steps. 
Once BeautifulSoup is installed, how i can use it in python code. If some one can share python code to achieve this.

Comment: Take a look at: [Web Scraping with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1792/web-scraping-with-python#t=201704051114226410689)

Answer (score 1):

The snippet in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43261897/retrieving-a-subset-of-hrefs-from-findall-in-beautifulsoup) might help you in retrieving all the links from a base url.

Comment: Thanks for this.. before running this, i feel beautifulSoup and pip are required. I am facing issue in installation. would request more details around that first.

Comment: If your operating system is windows just download python 3.6 which includes pip as bundled module. Then add your python 3.6 and python 3.6/scripts to your environment path. Then you can use pip install beautifulsoup4 from command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Your question provides no information of your OS or specific goal. I'm assuming you already have Python installed. 
[pip](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pip_(package_manager)) is command line tool to manage python packages. You can run the following command on your terminal

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

The [beautifulsoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) is a good place to get started on learning more.

Comment: Python is already installed, version Python 2.7.8. I am trying to install everythng through cmd. When i run command pip install beautifulsoup, it says 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,